# Can't download Chromium browser

Tags: 12.04, internet, chromium

I'm trying to download Chromium web browser but I'm getting this error message below, any help?

[image]

Comment: copy paste the error

Comment: check your internet connection.Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: i added screen-shot link and yes i have conn to the internet

Comment: change server and try again

Comment: little help with that?

Comment: Try it directly from the terminal. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` first to update your computer then `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`. Include any errors you may find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install `chromium-browser` through terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Because in some cases if you connected to the internet through `sakis3g` or anyother script, installing package through software-center won't work.But terminal does.